# How to get rid of virtual keyboard?

Tags: configure, onscreen-keyboard

I am using a hp 23 display on a laptop and when I open a new tab in Chrome, a virtual keyboard comes up on the screen.
How do I get rid of it as I have a keyboard on USB  which I use?

Answer (score 3):

Open **settings>Universal Access>Typing>Screen Keyboard**, you'll find it **On**, switch it to **Off**.

Comment: That was fast. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If the answer helped you, please consider accepting it.